# Combining icon bar with drop down in HTML?

Tags: html

I am trying to add a bar to my page, but due to my little HTML knowledge, I have a lot of problems realizing my idea.
Basically, I found this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_icon_bar.asp) where it is explained how to have an icon bar. But I want to combine it with drop-down options like shown on this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp). Is it possible to combine both? To goal would be if I press on a certain icon a drop-down menu should appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in order to do what you're describing, you have 2 options.  The first option is to do some tricks with CSS.  There's a thing called the "checkbox hack", but it is not straightforward for a beginner at all.  The second is more straightforward and involves JavaScript.

I'll paste my code here, so you can see what I did.

```js
const projectsTab = document.getElementById('projects')
const tabName = projectsTab.querySelector('.tab-name')
const projectLinks = document.querySelector('.project-links')

projectsTab.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const isOpen = projectLinks.classList.contains('open')

  if (isOpen) projectLinks.classList.remove('open')
  else projectLinks.classList.add('open')
})

// link event listeners
const links = [...projectLinks.children] // turn this into an array

links.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', e => {
  tabName.innerText = link.innerText
}))
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #222;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}

nav>* {
  flex: 1;
}

#logo {
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  background: #222;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.project-links {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  /* This is the height of this div + height of the nav bar */
  transform: translateY(-135%);
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.project-links.open {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.project-link {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
}

.project-link:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="logo">Logo</div>
  <ul>
    <li>About</li>
    <li id="projects">
      <span class="tab-name">Projects</span>
      <div class="project-links">
        <a class="project-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="project-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="project-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Click on the `Projects` tab to see this code in action.  By the way, I know this doesn't have 'icons', but that doesn't make a difference.  You can replace any of the text with whatever icons you want.

Comment: Yup, this answers exactly my question. Thanks a lot O:)

Comment: No problem. :))

Comment: Before I post a new question, is it possible to adjust the code so that if I lets say pick Link 2 from the drop down menu, then Instead of "Projects" to say "Link2"? My long term goal is the  users to pick the settings from that bar

Comment: Ah, ok sure.  No problem